# How to make existing Java code FIPS 140-2 compliant?

Tags: java, jce, fips

We have some Java library performing AES and RSA encryptions (using javax.crypto.Cipher).

A new requirement came in to make the code [FIPS 140-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2) compliant. Reading some articles what I understood is that I have to change the followings in the java.security file in JDK/JRE and recompile the code. Will that make my library FIPS 140-2 compliant?

```
#Use these three providers for FIPS compliant
security.provider.1=com.rsa.jsafe.provider.JsafeJCE
security.provider.2=com.rsa.jsse.JsseProvider
security.provider.3=sun.security.provider.Sun

#Disable the below providers for FIPS compliant
#security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
#security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
#security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
#security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
#security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
#security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
#security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
#security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
#security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
#security.provider.10=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
```

Is there any other changes I need to perform, like using any special jar, compiling with any argument, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

To be FIPS 140-2 compliant:

- You have to use a FIPS 140-2 approved cryptographic modules. It will provides the approved cryptographic implementations. See: https://csrc.nist.rip/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm. Read the description and/or the certificate to know the version to use.
- For each cryptographic operations (signature, encryption, key establishment, hashing ...) you also have to use approved security algorithms and parameters. Read: https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/140/2/final/documents/fips1402annexa.pdf. The document provides also a lot of references about the configuration of the security functions (key size, elliptic curve, ...).

For your case:

- AES128, AES192 or AES256 for encryption, with operation mode GCM, CCM, CTR, CBC, CFB, OFB (Or XTS for storage).
- RSA for Key Establishment or Signature with key size of 2048 bits minimum.